# How remove a custom settings from $sugar_config

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I create custom setting

```
  $configurator = new Configurator();
  $configurator->loadConfig(); 
  $configurator->config['test_value'] = 'test value'; 
  $configurator->saveConfig(); // save changes
```

How I can remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used it, but maybe:

```
$configurator->config['test_value'] = null;
$configurator->saveConfig();
```

Or:

```
unset($configurator->config['test_value']);  
$configurator->saveConfig();
```

Comment: @Vilix, I would put money on the unset(), but can you specify which one worked for you?